# map.find() not finding key c++

Tags: c++, mongodb

I am fetching values from MongoDB in a path pattern (db/collection/_id) and trying to insert data into a map where (Key=_id, value= full path). However, while I am trying to find certain map data by passing the key value to the function map.find(), it is returning map.end() even though the key exists.

Below is the code I have implemented, please look into this and let me know where I am going wrong.

```
        class myStructure {
            std::vector<string> arr;
        public:
            std::map<std::string, std::string> myMap;

        public:
            void add(char *ptr, size_t len, FILE *stream) {
                std::string key;
                unsigned found;

                while (getline(&ptr, &len, stream) != -1) {
                    std::string path(ptr);
                    found = path.find_last_of("/\\");
                    key = path.substr(found + 1);
                    myMap[key] = path;
                }
        // Iterating entire Map
                std::map<string, string>::iterator its1 = myMap.begin();
                std::cout << "myMap contains:\n";;
                for (its1 = myMap.begin(); its1 != myMap.end(); ++its1)
                    std::cout << its1->first << " => " << its1->second << '\n';
  // Output
//59dd9db3b3defb36a894a0f1 => /test/restaurants/59dd9db3b3defb36a894a0f1      
                std::string key_to_erase;
                std::cout << "Enter Key value to remove:" << std::endl;
                std::cin >> key_to_erase;
        //Erasing provided key value
                std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator iit = myMap.find(key_to_erase);

                if (iit == myMap.end()) {
                    std::cout << "key not found\n";
                }
                    // Check if iterator is valid.
                else {
                    // Remove the element pointed by iterator
                    myMap.erase(key_to_erase);
                    std::cout << "Element Removed" << std::endl;
                }
            }

        };

        int main(int, char**)
        {
            FILE *fpipe;
            std::string file;
            char *command = "/usr/bin/mongo --eval \"db.getSiblingDB(\\\"admin\\\").runCommand({ \\\"listDatabases\\\": 1 }).databases.forEach(function(database) {db = db.getSiblingDB(database.name);cols = db.getCollectionNames();cols.forEach(function(collectionName) {collection=db.getCollection(collectionName);keys=collection.find();keys.forEach(function(key){print(\\\"/\\\"+db+\\\"/\\\"+collectionName+\\\"/\\\"+key._id);});});});\"";
    //input values
    /*test/restaurants/59dd9db4b3defb36a894cd31
    test/restaurants/59dd9db4b3defb36a894cd32
    test/restaurants/59dd9db4b3defb36a894cd33
    test/restaurants/59dd9db4b3defb36a894cd34*/

            char *ptr = NULL;

            size_t len;
            std::array<char, 128> buffer;
            FILE *stream = popen (command, "r");
            myStructure ds;
            ds.add(ptr, len, stream);


        }
```

Comment: Your trim function seems like it would leave trailing spaces if there were no leading spaces. Try putting quotes around what you're printing when iterating through the map to be sure there's nothing invisible left. `std::cout << "'" << its1->first << "' => " << its1->second << '\n';`

Comment: Also, `std::cin >> key_to_erase` is already trimmed, so `trim(key_to_erase)` is redundant. `operator>>` ignores leading whitespace before scanning, and then stops scanning when it encounters whitespace

Comment: I already tried without trim function also. You can test this code on your end by removing trim function

Comment: We can't test this code on our end, we don't have access to your database and you haven't provided an example of your input.

Comment: Check now, I have added input parameters and also how key,value I am needing.

Comment: Seems fine to me. https://ideone.com/eVOGAn Run it in a debugger and step through, or add additional logging to validate that everything is as you think it is.

Comment: It looks good but can't we use it without key vector. I want to take key value from user and try to find it in map and its failing.
Iterator on maps is working fine on above code also, its failing when user provides a key value and we search that in map.

Comment: From [getline(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline): "The buffer is null-terminated **and includes the newline character, if one was found**."  You are not accounting for the newline character.

Comment: At some point you're going to have to work out why your input isn't matching your key values. Taking the input from `cin` makes no difference in the example I made. https://ideone.com/eVOGAn

Comment: @RetiredNinja There is no overload of `std::getline` that accepts a `FILE*`.  OP is using the POSIX `getline`, not the C++ `std::getline`.

Comment: @MilesBudnek My mistake. If there is a newline in the input string then OP would not have the output shown when iterating through the map. Even so, this is not a difficult problem to solve, either with a debugger or a few simple logs. If non-printable characters are the issue and you can't find them, print the strings character by character in hex and it'll be obvious when they are different.

Comment: Thank you guys it worked

Comment: @ShringaBais Why on earth are you shelling out to the mongo shell and parsing the reply rather than simply using the C++ driver to talk to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned we are getting newline character in the keys from `getline(&ptr, &len, stream)` and after removing that code works fine for user entries. I used below code to correct to remove newline characters

```
key.erase(std::remove(key.begin(), key.end(), '\n'), key.end());
```